# Continuing spline in python

Tags: python, recursion, scipy, time-series, spline

I'm doing spline and derivative of some time series data using scipy's [UnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html). It generally works fairly well, although the smoothing factor can be a bit of a pain to fine-tune.

My problem is, that my data set is updated with new data every few minutes or so (but not at pre-determined intervals). When new data is added, I would like to continue my spline/derivatives without having to re-compute the entire spline.

I have looked around for some kind of "recursive" spline method, but without luck. Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I should start looking, or perhaps a package that might be better suited for the job than scipy?

Comment: This is of course not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which you should provide. But how is this supposed to work? Your question asks from your fitting routine to anticipate the points that will be added later.

Comment: Normally spline is an interpolation between k=3 points (cubic spline) or k=4 points (quadratic spline). Scipy added a k=5 interpolation and a `variable until smoothing < s`. So if you choose the spline with k=3 and s=none, the spline will be stable except maybe for the last 3 points.

Comment: You say updated and added so I don't know if your dataset grows or changes. But if you're adding new data then keep only the knots from the old spline and combine with the new data. Weight the old knots heavily so that it has a significant influence on the next set of knots. Weights would have to adjusted to see how much you want the new data to affect the old data.

Answer (score 1):

Normally spline is an interpolation between `k=3` points (cubic spline) or `k=4` points (quadratic spline). Scipy added a `k=5` interpolation and a `variable until smoothing < s`.

So if you choose the spline with `k=3` and `s=none`, the spline will be stable except maybe for the last 3 points.

Comment: Can you provide a testable version? In my attempt with either a rolling window or chunks the splines of those fragments differ from each other and from the spline for the whole curve.

Comment: Maybe we wait for the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. Or maybe a request for more explanation from the user. Or maybe you rise your own question...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: No - you cannot continue the spline using UivariateSpline without having to re-compute the entire spline.

The longer answer is: In theory you might be able to compute an *interpolation* spline without having to re-compute the entire spline, but only under some constraints. However, I am not aware of any Python spline package (in scipy or elsewhere) that implements an interface to these constraints.

To see this consider the spline as a concatanation of polynomial segments with continuity constraints at the knot values.
For simplicity, let's restrict the discussion to cubic polynomials although it can be generalized to other degrees.
A spline interpolation problem is given a sequence of `(xi,yi)` pairs (the knot values and the function values at the knots) and computes a sequence of cubic polynomials that go through the function values `yi` at the knots `xi` and have first and second derivative continuity at the (inner) knots.

Now, consider a single polynomial segment, the input is a pair of points `(x0,y0)`, `(x1,y1)` and the result is a single cubic polynomial going through these points.
Notice that there are four degrees of freedom to construct the polynomial (since there are four coefficients to a cubic polynomial) but only two constraints - so there remain two degrees of freedom to construct the polynomial.
Adding additional segments adds four constraints for each segment (two positional `f(xi)=fi`, `fxi+1=fi+1`, and the continuity of first and second derivatives `f'(xi)=f'i`, `f''(xi)=f''i`), so the two degrees of freedom to the problem remain.

So, any spline interpolation problem has two degrees of freedom that need to be satisfied. 
This is why interpolation splines need two additional constraints - the most popular of these is probably the "natural spline" conditions which adds the constraints `f''(x0)=0`, `f''(x_m)=0` (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation).
Most packages do not give an interface to the two additonal constraints and choose them for you (usually the "natural spline" conditions).

In the context of the question, after you construct your spline from the first data set your first spline is totally defined.
Now, when you get an additional data set, in order to make it continue the first spline (without changing the first spline) you need to define the two derivative constraints `f'(x0=xm)=f'm, f''(x0=xm)=f''m` as the two additional constraints for the new data.
Only if you define these constraints will the new spline continue your first spline without modification.

However, as I said above, I am not aware of a Python package that enables you to define such constraints.